# how to track a UDP packet drop using proc command

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, network-programming, udp

I need to track UDP receive queue drop in my LINUX machine. for i am using the following command `cat /proc/net/udp and the output is

sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode
  20: 00000000:8614 00000000:0000 07 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000   500        0 4430600 2 ffff81007a40b380          `

Here i am not getting any info about udp drops..? is there anyway to customize proc/net/udp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways you can determine where packets are dropped throughout your networking stack. Packets may be dropped by the NIC or in various components of the networking system.

It's a bit tough to summarize because there are many components, each of them with separate files and tuning knobs. I wrote a long [blog post](http://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/06/22/monitoring-tuning-linux-networking-stack-receiving-data/) describing how to monitor and tune each component. Check it out; it should help explain how and where to get the data you are looking for about UDP drops.